# trying to change the focus change button from tab to enter in c# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

so as the title says im trying to change the tab button into enter button. i wrote this already and it kinda works

```cs
public class EnterBasedForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    public EnterBasedForm()
    {
        KeyPreview = true;
        KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(OnKeyPressed);
    }

    public void OnKeyPressed(object? sender, KeyEventArgs handler)
    {
        if (handler.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        }
    }
}
```

but when getting on a button this presses the button instead of changing the focus. and each time pressing enter it plays a sound. how can i disable the enter key functionallity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the Enter key in `ProcessCmdKey()`, force a Tab key with `base.ProcessTabKey()`, and then consume the Enter key so it doesn't go further by returning true:

```
public partial class EnterBasedForm : Form
{

    public EnterBasedForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            base.ProcessTabKey(true);
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

}
```